# Jest integration tests (with Postgres) randomly fail due to timeout on GitHub Actions

Tags: postgresql, github, jestjs, github-actions

I have tests that connect with Postgres randomly fail due to timeout issue on GitHub Actions. Randomly fail means it can occur on any test case not just only one case.

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 50000 ms for a hook.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

This issue never occurs on my local machine.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

No idea where I should start as I cannot reproduce on my local machine.